# Which Stack Exchange site is best suited for questions regarding sound theory?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where would be the proper stack exchange website to ask questions regarding sound theory ranging from the human ear and how it processes sound waves, to the equipment and mathematics behind them, all the way to the publishing and distribution process?

I could span all these questions across math.stackexchange.com, biology.stackexchange.com, history etc. But I need to ask questions about audio engineering in general without having to jump trough topics.

Comment: Some of your questions may be on topic on [Audio-Video production](http://avp.stackexchange.com/faq) or [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Ah. there you go! Thank you! That's actually the good answer.